# Missing crate when using rustc but not using cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using the epub crate on version 1.2.3 and my Cargo.toml is formatted as such

```
[package]
name = "cl-epub-reader"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
epub = "1.2.22"
```

and my main.rs is

```rust
use epub::doc::EpubDoc;
use epub::doc::NavPoint;
use std::env::args;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = args().collect();
    let doc = EpubDoc::new(&args[1]).unwrap();
//    assert!(doc.is_ok());
    println!("{:?}", doc.mdata("title"));
}
```

All it does is get the uses the path from the a user input then it gets the title metadata and printing it.

When I run `cargo run` it outputs an error about an error about going out of range, which is expected however when I run `rustc src/main.rs` the error is `` error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `epub`? ``
Does anyone know the cause of this and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `rustc` directly, you need to pass the appropriate options to tell the compiler where the crates are installed on your computer. `cargo` handles that automatically for you (you can use the `-v` option to `cargo build` to see the actual `rustc` command lines it uses).