# Rustdoc Doesn't Recognize Imported Dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml, rust-crates, rustdoc

I just created a new Rust project and introduced one dependency in `main.rs`. When I try to run `rustdoc src/main.rs`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `rand`?
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
```

Even though `Cargo.toml` has that dependency already, it's installed and in `Cargo.lock`, it's imported in `main.rs` through `use rand;` and the project builds successfully, without any issues.

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

I saw some answers point to edition being absent or set to earlier versions as the cause; this is not the case here. I tried creating documents for fresh libraries or binaries as described [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/what-is-rustdoc.html), but it works until I introduce a dependency, when the same error repeats.

Project structure (the `rustdoc` command is run from root):

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── readme.md
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you run `cargo doc` from the root directory? If it works please add the output from `cargo doc --verbose`.

Comment: Are you running `rustdoc` directly? (You should be running `cargo doc`).

Comment: Just to make the point even clearer: Your config file is named `Cargo.toml`, indicating that it needs `cargo` to resolve the dependencies ;)

Comment: For more info, look at the relevent section in [the rustdoc documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/what-is-rustdoc.html#using-rustdoc-with-cargo).

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969831/missing-crate-when-using-rustc-but-not-using-cargo/69972075#69972075 (that one is about `rustc`, but the same applies to `rustdoc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the solution, `cargo` has an integration with `rustdoc` which solves the dependency problem automatically - the example given in the basic usage documentation only works when there are no dependencies. Just running `cargo doc` in the root will generate the wanted documentation, however under the `target/doc` path.

Thanks for the help!